# Accessing rest service hosted on aws ec2 from other domain (jquery ajax) but getting CORS error

Tags: rest, cors, jax-rs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am endup with all possible solution on net but unable to passthrough my problem. Experts please help.
Problem : Created a struts2 app and hosted on Elastic beanstalk in which one class is exposed as Rest service. Class is as follows

```
package com.xeon.adworld.restws;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.Admaster;
import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.AdmasterDAO;
import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.Businessacc;
import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.BusinessaccDAO;
import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.Restservicehitinfo;
import com.xeon.adworld.hibernatepojos.RestservicehitinfoDAO;

@Path("FetchBusSer")
public class FetchBusAds {
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FetchBusAds.class);
@Context
  private HttpServletRequest request;

@Context
  private HttpServletResponse response;


//@GET
@OPTIONS
@Path("/fetchbusads")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response fetchBusinessAds() {

    try{
        String partnerId=(null!=request.getParameter("pid")?request.getParameter("pid").toLowerCase():"");
        String ip=(null!=request.getParameter("ip")?request.getParameter("ip").toLowerCase():"");

    BusinessaccDAO businessaccDAO=new BusinessaccDAO();
    List<Businessacc> busList=businessaccDAO.findByBusuuid(partnerId);
    if(busList.size()>0){

    AdmasterDAO admasterDAO=new AdmasterDAO();
    //PersonaladsDAO personaladsDAO = new PersonaladsDAO();
    List<Admaster> adsList= admasterDAO.getLatestAds();
    StringBuffer allAdsString = new StringBuffer(
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><main>");

    for (Admaster result : adsList) {
        allAdsString.append("<data>");
        allAdsString.append("<imgpath>"+result.getImagepath()+"</imgpath>");
        allAdsString.append("</data>");
    }

    allAdsString.append("</main>");
    System.out.println("allAds : string 7ndst: " + allAdsString.toString());

    return Response.ok(allAdsString.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept").build();
    }else{
        RestservicehitinfoDAO restservicehitinfoDAO=new RestservicehitinfoDAO();
        Restservicehitinfo restservicehitinfo = new Restservicehitinfo();
        restservicehitinfo.setIpaddress(ip);
        restservicehitinfo.setAdpartnerid(partnerId);
        restservicehitinfo.setVisitingdate(new java.util.Date());
        restservicehitinfo.setDescription("Bot or False hit");
        restservicehitinfoDAO.save(restservicehitinfo);
        String result="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><main></main>";

        return Response.ok(result).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept").build();

    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("error in fetchbusads rest service : " + e);
    return null;
}
}
```

}

=====================================
Client code used to call this class is as below

```
url="http://<<domainname.com>>/rest/FetchBusSer/fetchbusads?pid="+partnerId+"&ip="+ipadd;
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
crossOrigin: true,
url: url,
contentType: "application/xml",
 success: function(data){
alert('insuccess : ' + data);
if(data){
//alert(xml);
   var main  = data;
    var image;
   var method=eval(main.getElementsByTagName("main"));
   for(var i=0;i<method.length;i++){
    var tmp=main.getElementsByTagName("data");
     var infoDiv='';

      for(var j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){
      if(tmp[j].getElementsByTagName('imgpath')[0].firstChild!=null){   

         if(j==0)
         infoDiv+='<li style="display:block;">';
         else
         infoDiv+='<li style="display:none;">';
         infoDiv+='<div class="adcontentDynList">';
        image=tmp[j].getElementsByTagName('imgpath')[0].firstChild.data;
        var url='http://servveradd/hitFromRsServiceLink.action?pid='+partnerId;
         infoDiv+='<a href='+url+' target="_blank">';
         infoDiv+='<img src="http://serveradd'+image+'" class="imageset"/>';
         infoDiv+='</a>';
         infoDiv+='</div>';
         infoDiv+='</li>';
        // alert(infoDiv);
        }
        }
         document.getElementById("ticker_"+partnerId).innerHTML=infoDiv;
    }
}else{
}
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('something bad happened : ' + errorThrown+'-- '+textStatus+'--'+jqXHR); }
});
```

=======================================================

Success so far - When i look in to firebug NET tab, I get to see two calls instead of one. The first call is perfect with **response** and its **header and origin** set.. But the implicit second call do not contain any response. Please see the screen shot
    I am getting the response in browser while i see through firebug NET tab..

[Check the two calls instead of 1, First is correct and 2nd is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdOoC.jpg)

====== another pic is of firebug console =========

[second image is for console of firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo239.png)
Experts I took a full day to get this done but unsuccessful. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Anybody interested to answer this challenging question.. Experts here?

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference, I found the answer. The reason of the error was that string object was not able to convert in to Response object properly. Solution is as below
instead of returning this

```
return Response.ok(allAdsString.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept").build();
```

I change the statement as

```
return Response.ok().entity(new GenericEntity<String>(allAdsString.toString()) {}).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET").build();
```

And got it resolved